# Having trouble with pygame.translation.rotation

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm testing rotation for a racing game. 
Here is the code...

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
degree = 0
WHITE = 250,250,250
rect2 = pygame.rect = (100,100,50,50)
WINDOWWIDTH = 1200
WINDOWHEIGHT = 750

thing = pygame.image.load('thing.bmp')
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Teh test')

while True:
    rect2 = pygame.rect = (100,100,50,50)
    degree += 2

    if degree >= 50:
        degree = 0

    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
    thing = pygame.transform.rotate(thing,degree)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,rect2)
    screen.blit(thing,(100,100))
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(60)
```

So the issue is that when I run it the rect gets HUGE and the image spins off the screen. What am I doing wrong?
(The more answers the better.) Thanks!

(Using python 3.3 and pygame for that version.)

Comment: I'm curious why "the more answers the better". Shouldn't one good answer be sufficient? If not, the question would be too broad for SO anyway. (I don't see that being the case here though.)

Comment: The last question I asked was complicated a ton of people answered it wrong.

Comment: Considering none of those answers were accepted by you as correct, clearly *more* answers does *not* equate to a good answer.

Comment: It raises the chances of finding a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't overwrite `thing`. This way you cumulate degrees.

First you rotate `thing` 2 degrees, than you rotate `thing` 4 degrees +2 degrees from previous rotation = 6 degrees, than you rotate `thing` 6 degrees +4 degrees from previous rotation +2 degrees from previous rotation = 12 degrees, etc.

When `degee >= 50` you get `degee = 0` but you still have rotated `thing` (50 + 48 + 46 + ... + 2 )

Use `thing2`

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# constants 
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

WHITE = 250,250,250
WINDOWWIDTH = 1200
WINDOWHEIGHT = 750

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# game
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

pygame.init()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Teh test')

#thing = pygame.image.load('thing.bmp')
thing = pygame.image.load('player.png')

rect2 = pygame.rect = (100,100,50,50)

degree = 0

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# mainloop
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

running = True
while running:

    # events

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

    # calculations

    degree += 2

    if degree >= 50:
        degree = 0

    thing2 = pygame.transform.rotate(thing, degree)

    # draws

    screen.fill((40, 40, 40))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,rect2)
    screen.blit(thing2,(100,100))

    pygame.display.update()

    # clock

    mainClock.tick(30)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# exit
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

pygame.quit()
```

BTW: never overwrite oryginal image because image rotated even 360 degrees never be as pretty as oryginal.

---

*My PNG image used in code 'player.png'*

[image]

*PNG in game (Python 2.7, Linux Mint 16)*

[image]

Comment: So I tried it and... There is a square around the spinning object. How do I get rid of it? (It also changes sizes.)

Comment: I use PNG image - maybe it is problem with BMP file. I and my image to answer.

Comment: I add PNG and screenshot to answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm kind of making a series of questions as I come across issues. So just check on my questions every now and then.